# when uploading image (one at a time) to firebase storage the first one gets uploaded when i upload the second one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using firebase storage to upload images, here's the problem
when I upload image A it shows up as some 9bytes file in storage folder,
then I upload image B, the image A shows up in storage, it returns the link of it too.

This sequence goes on for however many images I upload.

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong?

Here's my code:

```
<input
          type="file"
          id="file"
          ref={inputFile}
          style={{ display: "none" }}
          onChange={handleImageChange}
        />
```

handleImageChange():

```
  const handleImageChange = (e) => {
   if (e.target.files[0]) {
    setImage(e.target.files[0]);
    uploadFiles();
  }}
```

uploadFiles finction:

```
  const uploadFiles = () => {
  const uploadTask = storage.ref(`ProfilePictures/${user.uid}.png`).put(image);
  uploadTask.on(
    "state_changed",
    (snapshot) => {
      const prog = Math.round(
        (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
      );
      setProgress(prog);
    },
    (error) => console.log(error),
    () => {
      storage
        .ref("ProfilePictures")
        .child(`${user.uid}.png`)
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then((url) => {
          console.log(url);
        });
    }
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is `uploadFiles` gets triggered before the state changes.

That's why it is showing the previous state (image) in the Storage Folder.

**Corrected Code:**

```js
const handleImageChange = (e) => {
  if (e.target.files[0]) {
    setImage(e.target.files[0]);
    uploadFiles(e.target.files[0]);
  }
};

const uploadFiles = (file) => {
  const uploadTask = storage.ref(`ProfilePictures/${user.uid}.png`).put(file);
  uploadTask.on(
    "state_changed",
    (snapshot) => {
      const prog = Math.round(
        (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
      );
      setProgress(prog);
    },
    (error) => console.log(error),
    () => {
      storage
        .ref("ProfilePictures")
        .child(`${user.uid}.png`)
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then((url) => {
          console.log(url);
        });
    }
  );
};
```